# Extract Data From Firestore document.getData()

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, server

**I want to Extract Data From Firestore document.getData()**

> What I Have To Do Is:

*Get Data From Firestore And Extract That Data In Java File And Show That Extracted Data In The Text View*

> My Full Android Java Code

```
package com.verify.humanverify.ui.dashboard;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.verify.humanverify.R;
import com.verify.humanverify.ui.notifications.NotificationsViewModel;

import java.util.List;

public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.aadharnoni);
        dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                db.collection("Details").whereEqualTo("Person E-Mail", acct.getEmail()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d("Data", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                textView.setText(document.getData()+document.getId());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w("Error", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

**Main Data Coming From Firestore**

```
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d("Data", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                textView.setText(document.getData()+document.getId());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.w("Error", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
```

**I Want To Extract Data From Here**

```
Log.d("Data", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
textView.setText(document.getData()+document.getId());
```

**Get Data From This Method**
`document.getData()`

**My XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_image"
                android:layout_width="203dp"
                android:layout_height="208dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aadharnoni"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_image"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aadhar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aadharno"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aadhar"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gender"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Text Views Where I Have To Show The Data**

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/aadharnoni"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_image"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aadhar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aadharno"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aadhar"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/denk_one"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gender"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

**This Is The Collection Which I Am Getting**

```
 D/Data: UN5RqHsimOvXAMF1sTtY => {Person Photo URL=https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhQbVE3TmhXdpi-vxYSa5QuUxOXVQ95zYotBSzv=s96-c, Person Id=112019185671391718103, Aadhar=XXXXXX, Person Given Name=Krishna, Driving License=XXXXXX, Person Name=Krishna Wadhwani, Person Family Name=Wadhwani, Person E-Mail=kwswhwmw@gmail.com, Date Of Birth=XXXXXX}
```

***I Want To Show These All Fields In Different TextViews***
**For Example**

`Person E-Mail In E-Mail Text View`

*And So On...*

***Thanks In Advance From THE KOOL WINGS***

Comment: Please Answer This

Comment: Please post your database structure so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want single field data. Then just use `.get(/*path*/)`.

You can try something like this to get `Name` :

```
Log.e("name", document.get("Person Given Name").toString());
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish Its Now Working